# Common Second-Order Kernels - Uniform, Gaussian and Epanechnikov

Tags: self-study, kernel-smoothing

How can one calculate the $\ R(k) $ and $\ K_2(k) $
for the common second-order kernels?

For the Rectangular Kernal the answer is $\ R(k) = 1/2 $   and  $\ K_2(k)=1/3 $

How can you derive this?

And how would it look like for Gaussian and Epanechnikov?

Note: Moments of a kernel are $\ K_j(k) $ here j=2 since we deal with second order moments.

Roughness = $\ R(k) $ , second moment = $\ K_2(k) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following definitions need to be checked for a kernel $k$:

$$
K_j(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi^jk(\psi)d\psi
$$
as well as
$$
R(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(\psi)^2d\psi
$$
For the rectangular kernel we for example have $k(\psi)=0.5\cdot 1_{\{|\psi|\leq1\}}$. The area under this rectangular function is one, $\int_{-1}^10.5\cdot 1_{\{|\psi|\leq1\}}d\psi=1$, so that this kernel, like most conventional ones, has the properties of a density function.

Its roughness follows as
$$
R(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (0.5\cdot 1_{\{|\psi|\leq1\}})^2d\psi=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1 1_{\{|\psi|\leq1\}}d\psi=\frac{1}{4}\cdot2=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Next,
\begin{align*}
K_2(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi^20.5\cdot 1_{\{|\psi|\leq1\}}d\psi\\
&=0.5\int_{-1}^1\psi^2d\psi\\
&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
For the Gaussian and Epanechnikov, for which the same integrations are to be carried out, you should obtain $K_2(k)=1$, $R(k)=1/(2\sqrt{\pi})$ and $K_2(k)=1/5$, $R(k)=3/5$.

Comment: Many thanks! Would you be so kind and show the steps in between. I do not see how your get 0.51 and the other solutions! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Christoph --  do you mean $\frac12$ where you have $0.51$ there?

Comment: Yes! I would like to understand each single step.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0.5 times.

Comment: Thanks! But what steps do you have to take to get 0.5?

Comment: None, that is just the definition of the kernel. One half ensures that the kernel integrates to one.

Comment: So 3/5 ensures that it integrates to 1 for the Epanechnikov. But how can I show this in a formal way?

Comment: And how can I show the 1/3 for the second moment?

Comment: I made some further clarifications.